# Rooting a Samsung Tab S

Tags: root, tablet

I have a **Samsung Tab S 8.4" with Android 5.0.2, Build # LRX22G.T700XXU1BOE3**.

I want to root it, but, knowing it's a delicate process, I don't want to mess it up.

I looked around first, and found things that may work, but I don't feel comfortable making the risk of bricking my tablet.

So, I came here.

I have Ubuntu and Windows 10 avaliable to use, and want to know:

- How can I root my device?
- Is there any way to *totally* back it up so I can use abd or something to restore it if I brick tt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There a ton of resources to do this online. You could stop by [xda-developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-tab-s/development/root-cf-autoroot-twrp-t800-t3079488) for rooting needs. This is

> [ROOT][RECOVERY][ALL IN ONE] Cf-Autoroot-twrp-T700/705/800/805/Tab S- UPDATE 23/4/15

You can do backups before rooting:

1. On the computer [via ADB.](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-create-a-full-backup-of-your-android-device-without-root/)
2. [4 app options](http://www.technorms.com/39708/android-backup-4-best-options):

   - Holo Backup
   - Helium
   - G Cloud Backup
   - Super Backip